# ReactBootstrap Grid RowSpan not working

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, col

Here is an image of the control, as you can see the rowSpan is not working and the second row starts below the first one.  I would like the Base Role select to be directly below the Role Name input.
[image]

[image]

I tried adding the rowSpan={5} attribute as you can see above, but it did not do anything.  I also tried rowspan and other variations of the attribute's case.

As a workaround I am considering adding a parent table and housing this table in the first column and the textarea for Description in the second column but would like to achieve this with some type of rowSpan functionality if possible.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I have a ReactBootstrap Grid control and I want to add a column for a Description and give it a rowSpan of 5 so the other column is in line with this one and does not start after the end of this one.

```
                    <ReactBootstrap.Grid style={{marginTop: 10}} fluid={true}>
                        <ReactBootstrap.Row>
                            <ReactBootstrap.Col sm={6} md={6}>
                                <Input label="Name:" ref={(r) => this.name= r} className={this.state.errors.name} defaultValue={object.name} onChange={ value => this.onFieldChange("name", value) } maxLength="50" />
                            </ReactBootstrap.Col>
                            <ReactBootstrap.Col sm={6} md={6} rowSpan={5} >

                            <div className="label">Description:</div>
                            <textarea ref="notes" rows="15" onChange={ this.onChangeDescription } style={{ width: "99%" }} disabled={ object.isDeleted }>
                                { object.description }
                            </textarea>

                        </ReactBootstrap.Col>
                        </ReactBootstrap.Row>
```

Comment: I dont understand what you want to achieve, can you add some drawing of your objective ?

Comment: @AshKander you can see the images that I added above.

Comment: I am not sure if what I want to do is supported.  The react code is translated into HTML divs.

Comment: Structure of resulting HTML should be like `<div md6 sm6><!--inputs--></div><div md6 sm6><!---textarea--></div>`

Comment: Yes but I did not write react and currently it does not translate into that @Zydnar

Comment: You have to change react components so they will render this structure. Which component returns select? Can you provide code of this component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell RowSpan is not supported for a React Bootstrap Grid Column.  If anybody finds out different or this feature is added in the future please let me know or post an updated answer below.

My work around was to add 2 columns to the original grid, where the first column holds another grid that has 1 column and rows with all of the data that would normally appear in the first column and the second column holds the multi-line text area.

You can see this was achieved, however I found some issues with the width of the inner controls in the first column, so I went about manually setting their width values.

[image]

Here is my code.

```js
<ReactBootstrap.Grid style={{marginTop: 10}} fluid={true}>
<ReactBootstrap.Row>
 <ReactBootstrap.Col sm={6} md={6}>

   <ReactBootstrap.Grid >
    <ReactBootstrap.Row>
     <ReactBootstrap.Col sm={6} md={6}>
      <Input label="Role Name:" ref={(r) => this.roleName = r} className={this.state.errors.roleName} width="300" defaultValue={role.name} onChange={ value => this.onFieldChange("roleName", value) } maxLength="50" />
     </ReactBootstrap.Col>
    </ReactBootstrap.Row>
    <ReactBootstrap.Row>
     <ReactBootstrap.Col sm={6} md={6}>
      <div>
      <div className="label" >Base Role:</div>
       <Select ref={(r) => this.baseRole = r} className={this.state.errors.baseRole} style={{ width: "300px" }} options={baseRoles} onChange={this.onChangeBaseRole} value={ role.baseRoleId } clearable={false} backspaceRemoves={false} />
      </div>
     </ReactBootstrap.Col>
    </ReactBootstrap.Row>
    <ReactBootstrap.Row>
     <ReactBootstrap.Col sm={6} md={6}>
      <div>
      <div className="label" >Startup Module:</div>
       <Select ref={(r) => this.defaultModule = r} className={this.state.errors.defaultModule} style={{ width: "300px" }} options={defaultModules} onChange={this.onChangeDefaultModule} value={ role.moduleId } clearable={false} backspaceRemoves={false} />
      </div>
     </ReactBootstrap.Col>
    </ReactBootstrap.Row>
    <ReactBootstrap.Row>
     <ReactBootstrap.Col sm={6} md={6}>
        <Input label="Allow Company Access" type="checkbox" ref={(r) => this.companyAccess = r} className={ this.state.errors.companyAccess} checked={ role.companyAccess} onChange={ value => this.onFieldChange("companyAccess", value) } />
     </ReactBootstrap.Col>
    </ReactBootstrap.Row>
    <ReactBootstrap.Row>
     <ReactBootstrap.Col sm={6} md={6}>
        <Input label="Restrict Application Access" type="checkbox" ref={(r) => this.applicationGrant = r} className={ this.state.errors.applicationGrant} checked={ role.applicationGrant} onChange={ value => this.onFieldChange("applicationGrant", value) } />
     </ReactBootstrap.Col>
    </ReactBootstrap.Row>
   </ReactBootstrap.Grid>
  </ReactBootstrap.Col>
 
  <ReactBootstrap.Col sm={6} md={6} RowSpan={5} >

   <div className="label">Description:</div>
   <textarea ref="notes" rows="15" onChange={ this.onChangeNotes } style={{ width: "99%" }} disabled={ role.isDeleted }>
    { role.description }
   </textarea>
  </ReactBootstrap.Col>
 </ReactBootstrap.Row>

</ReactBootstrap.Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so a basic way to achieve this with 'basic bootstrap' would be

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-6">
      <div>Hi man</div>
      <div>after the text area</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-sm col-xs-12">
      <div>Hi man</div>
    </div>        
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <textarea rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="hidden-sm col-xs-12">
      <div>after the text area</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Trying to convert it to react-bootstrap gives (code below not tested)

```
<ReactBootstrap.Row>
    <ReactBootstrap.Col className="hidden-xs" sm={6}>
      <div>Hi</div>
      <div>after the text area</div>
    </ReactBootstrap.Col>
    <ReactBootstrap.Col className="hidden-sm">
      <div>Hi man</div>
    </ReactBootstrap.Col>        
    <ReactBootstrap.Col sm={6}>
      <textarea rows="5"></textarea>
    </ReactBootstrap.Col>
    <ReactBootstrap.Col className="hidden-sm">
      <div>after the text area</div>
    </ReactBootstrap.Col>
</ReactBootstrap.Row>
```

and since we can see code dupplication here you probably want some functions to build the content of the 'Hi man' and 'after the text area' areas.

Comment: I dont think this is right.  You have 4 columns.  Not sure if you actually understand the question.

Comment: Ash you can see my answer below, I was able to get this to work.

Comment: So you actually just wanted a 2-column layout ? that was pretty unclear based on your inital question

Answer (score 0):

the row is behaving correctly. The simple fact is that the height of the description column is forcing the entire row to have that height. ofcourse the next row comes in under this. in order to achieve what you want you simply have to insert your base role, startup module, allow and restrict company access inputs into the same column that the role name is in and not have them in a seperate row.

```
 <ReactBootstrap.Grid style={{marginTop: 10}} fluid={true}>
                    <ReactBootstrap.Row>
                        <ReactBootstrap.Col sm={6} md={6}>
                            <Input label="Name:" ref={(r) => this.name= r} className={this.state.errors.name} defaultValue={object.name} onChange={ value => this.onFieldChange("name", value) } maxLength="50" />

 // insert your base role, startup module, allow and restric company access inputs here

                        </ReactBootstrap.Col>
                        <ReactBootstrap.Col sm={6} md={6} rowSpan={5} >

                        <div className="label">Description:</div>
                        <textarea ref="notes" rows="15" onChange={ this.onChangeDescription } style={{ width: "99%" }} disabled={ object.isDeleted }>
                            { object.description }
                        </textarea>

                    </ReactBootstrap.Col>
                    </ReactBootstrap.Row>
```

share edit flag